# In a node.js app using express, how can one call response.redirect from within a mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm writing my first Node.js app, using Express and Mongoose. The relevant excerpts from my code are below.

`res.redirect('/lobby')` is called from within a mongoose query (`models.User.findOne`), and doesn't work. Note that every bit of code, including the reading of the database, the redirect and the `checkAuth` function worked fine before I wrote the mongoose query. The code is executed as it should (I checked with console output) and throws no errors, but the actual redirect doesn't take place!

```
//Middleware

function checkAuth(req,res,next){
    console.log("Test output 4");
    if(!req.session.user_id){
        res.sendfile(path.join(root,'public/no_auth.html'));
    }else{
        console.log("Test output 5");
        next();
        console.log("Test output 8");
    }
};

//Routing

app.get('/lobby',checkAuth,function(req,res){
    console.log("Test output 6");
    res.sendfile(path.join(root,'lobby.html'));
    console.log("Test output 7");
});

//Login & Registration

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var post=req.body;
    if(post.user=='' || post.password=='' || post.platform==''){
        res.send(200,{success:false,details:'empty'});
    }else if(post.platform!=platform_password){
        res.send(200,{success:false,details:'platform'});
    }else{
        models.User.findOne({'name':post.user},'name password',function(err,user){
            if(err){
                console.info(err);
            }else if(post.password!=user.password){ //TODO figure out hash and salt stuff
                res.send(200,{success:false,details:'password'});
            }else{
                console.log("Test output 1: "+user.name);
                req.session.user_id=user.name;
                console.log("Test output 2: "+req.session.user_id);
                res.redirect('/lobby'); //<- this doesn't work
                console.log("Test output 3");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Screenshots of Node.js output:

[image]

Screenshot of the request/response details in the Firefox console:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try a `console.log(something)` immediately before your redirect call?

Comment: Yes. Before, and after the redirect call both. Prints out fine.

Comment: How about a `console.log` right before the call to `next()` in the middleware?

Comment: Yep, it outputs there too. And it also outputs inside the routing function, before as well as after res.sendfile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if(err){
            console.info(err);
            //You need to send a response here.
            //Each request must always get exactly one response no matter
            //how your code logic branches.
            //Otherwise, this request will just hang until timeout, which is bad
            res.send(500, err);
            //also, using early returns instead of a big if/else tree is cleaner IMHO
        }else if(post.password!=user.password){ //TODO figure out hash and salt stuff
            res.send(200,{success:false,details:'password'});
        }else{
            req.session.user_id=user.name;
            //This should work just fine.
            //In the comments you claim a console.log before and after this print
            //out but this "doesn't work".
            //1. I have good reason to be dubious of your claims here.
            // Clear your mind and double check yourself.
            //2. Get some technical detail beyond "Doesn't work".
            // Use curl and see what happens. Does the request just hang unresponded?
            res.redirect('/lobby'); //<- this doesn't work
        }
```

Comment: I edited my code in the post to show `console.log` calls and added screenshots of the node.js output as well as the request details shown in the Firefox console. Everything seems to be executed just fine... except that in my browser, the redirect doesn't take place. If I manually enter `localhost/lobby` into my browser bar, the routing works, and the auth too.

Comment: You are doing an ajax XmlHttpRequest. Those don't automatically do redirects like a normal browser page load. You have to manually in browser js change `window.location` based on the server response's `Location` header.

Comment: Oh okay... Didn't think it made a difference on the server side of things. Thansk!